# Java Pattern class - Which regex to make for getting string from outer brackets?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get string from other string having multiple layers of brackets, but I have problem with making good regular expression. How looks desired expression?

I tried expression `\((.*?)\)` but the expression is getting first bracket which see...

For example, when I have input string

```
(many things including things in inner brackets (like this))
```

I expect `group(1)` having value

```
many things including things in inner brackets (like this)
```

but actual value of `group(1)`

```
is many things including things in inner brackets (like this
```

Comment: Try making the other bracket part of your matcher group: `\((.*?\))\)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get rid of that non-greedy quantifier so your regex can match exhaustively and only stop at last `)` instead of the earlier one which is happening because of your non-greedy expression. Just change your regex from `\((.*?)\)` to `\((.*)\)`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/O7Idjo/1)**